# Parse nmap output file to print a list of IP with all open ports using awk

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, nmap

I would like to find the list of IP address with all open ports using `awk` command.

My nmap output file is:

```
# Nmap 7.01 scan initiated Sat Mar 18 06:27:08 2017 as: nmap -oG output.txt -T4 -f -iL iplist.txt
Host: 10.0.0.99 ()    Status: Up
Host: 10.0.0.99 ()    Ports: 135/open/tcp//msrpc///, 139/open/tcp//netbios-ssn///, 445/open/tcp//microsoft-ds///, 514/filtered/tcp//shell///, 554/open/tcp//rtsp///, 10243/open/tcp//unknown///    

Host: 192.168.0.1 ()    Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.1 ()    Ports: 135/open/tcp//msrpc///, 139/open/tcp//netbios-ssn///, 445/open/tcp//microsoft-ds///, 10243/open/tcp//unknown/// 

Host: 192.168.0.101 ()    Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.101 ()    Status: Up
# Nmap done at Sat Mar 18 06:29:02 2017 -- 3 IP addresses (3 hosts up) scanned in 113.19 seconds
```

Expected Output :

```
10.0.0.99   135
10.0.0.99   139
10.0.0.99   445
10.0.0.99   514
10.0.0.99   554
10.0.0.99   10243
192.168.0.1 135
192.168.0.1 139
192.168.0.1 445 
192.168.0.1 10243
```

output saved in another file (e.g. parse.txt)

Comment: doesn't nmap have a variety of output-formatting options already?

Answer (score 2):

You asked for `awk`, but this is simple to do with Perl, since it makes it easy to iterate over multiple matches of a regex.

```
$ perl -ne '$host = $1 if /^Host: (\S+)/; while(m,(\d+)/open,g) 
    { print "$host\t$1\n" } ' < nmap.out 
10.0.0.99       135
10.0.0.99       139
...


perl -ne                       # Run the code for each input line
'$host = $1 if /^Host: (\S+)/  # If the line starts with "Host: ", 
                               # save the next non-whitespace string
while( m,(\d+)/open,g ) {      # Go through all matches of `<digits>/open`
                               # on the line, catching the digits
    print "$host\t$1\n"        # Print the saved hostname and the matched digits.
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

An awk approach:

```
$ awk -F'[/ ]' '{h=$2; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="open"){print h,$(i-1)}}}' file 
10.0.0.99 135
10.0.0.99 139
10.0.0.99 445
10.0.0.99 554
10.0.0.99 10243
192.168.0.1 135
192.168.0.1 139
192.168.0.1 445
192.168.0.1 10243
```

The `-F[/ ]` sets the input field separator to `/` or a space. This means that the host IP will be `$2` and both the port number and the word "open" will be on their own fields. We can therefore iterate over all fields of a line (`for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){}`) and, if the current field is `open`, print the hostname and the previous field (the port): `if($i=="open"){print h,$(i-1)}`.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think I was able to put across my viewpoint clearly here. What
>   I want to emphasize is that
>   instead of having an explicit loop, we can `piggyback` on the regex m// to do the looping for us,
>   below is the restructured regex for greater clarity:

```
perl -lne '
    /^
        Host: \s+ (\S+) \s+         # stuff $1 with hostname
        .+?:                        # seek the nearest colon :
        (?:                         # setup a loop
           \s+(\d+)\/open\/\S+      # this pattern should repeat
           (?{ print "$1\t$2" })    # print hostname+digits foreach turn
        )* # (?{ CODE }) does a code execution during regex search
    /x;
' yourfile
```